# Video mode not supported (3 times!)

Tags: boot, nvidia, kubuntu, display-resolution, live-cd

I am having the same issue with three separate monitors! I am quite frustrated that no part of the live cd will load for kubuntu 16.10. I get my bios splash screen, then the initial cd loading screen (ruler = CD), the Kubuntu logo, and finally the above message (or some variation on that depending on the monitor I'm using).

What is the deal? What is the default resolution for this thing? I have no problems with resolutions of 1680x1050 on all of my three monitors using windows. I have been searching for solutions, but I don't think there is one - they all require you to boot some type of command prompt and even with Ctrl-Alt-F1 I need to login (and I don't know the password for the live-cd).

Answer (score 0):

I disconnected my other monitor (I have a dual monitor setup) and I was able to install the OS. I then rebooted with both monitors (the second wouldn't recognize without a reboot - which was odd). The monitor I had connected worked, but the newly connected one had it's refresh rate insanely high (causing it to not draw that screen).

After adjusting the settings to a more reasonable 60hz (down from the 120hz default) I got both monitors working. Now however I am getting graphical glitches whenever my screen updates (like snow in small portions of the screen). I am installing the proprietary drivers now to see if that fixes the issue.

UPDATE: The Nvidia drivers seem to have fixed my issue.